# Error traversing and printing singly linked list in C

Tags: c, pointers, printing, linked-list

Lost Noob, trying to read in a file line by line, i.e. "one", "two", "three" and add same to an ordered linked list (which I believe I have working). However, I can't figure out the syntax/logic for my traverse_and_print list function (and don't understand *(go to here and get value), &(get address) and -> that well. My mostly working code is on repl.it at https://repl.it/@MichaelB4/DeafeningTreasuredMathematics

```
// A complete working C program to demonstrate all insertion methods 
// from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-2- inserting-a-node/

#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include<string.h>

// Create structure for a linked list node 

struct Node 
{ 
    const char *data; 
    struct Node *next; 
}; 

struct Node *head;

// Given a reference (pointer to pointer) to the head of a list and a char*, appends a new node at the end
void append(struct Node** head_ref, const char *new_data) 
{ 
    // 1. allocate node
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 

    struct Node *last = *head_ref;  // used in step 5

    // 2. put in the data
    new_node-> data  = new_data; 

    // 3. Set new_node.next to Null, as it will be inserted at tail of list 
    new_node -> next = NULL;

    // 4. If the Linked List is empty, then make the new node as head
    if (*head_ref == NULL) 
    { 
        *head_ref = new_node;
        //printf("head\n");
        printf("%s", new_node -> data); 
        return; 
    } 

    // 5. Else traverse till the last node

    while (last -> next != NULL)  
        last = last -> next;
        printf("%s", new_node -> data); 

    // 6. Change the next of last node, have last node point to one just inserted, the new node at the end of the list, tail 

    last -> next = new_node; 
    return; 
} 

void traverse_and_printList(head){
    struct Node* current = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    current = head;
    while (head -> next != NULL)
        printf("%s", current -> data);
        current -> next = current;

}

/* Driver program to test above functions*/
int main() 
{ 
    // set up a file point to File to be opened
    FILE* fp;
    // holds contents of each line/word 
    char buffer[255]; 

    fp = fopen("words.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open infile"); 
        return 2;
    }

    /* create an empty node */
    struct Node* head = NULL; 

    int counter = 0;
    char *head_value[255]; 

    while(fgets(buffer, 255, (FILE*) fp)){
        //printf("%s", buffer);
        append(&head, buffer);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    traverse_and_printList(head);
    printf("\n");
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confused about the purpose that the `current` pointer serves.

First, you don't need to allocate memory for it.  You're not trying to store anything new.  The `current` pointer is just a value that helps you move over the items in your list.

Second, you shouldn't modify the list's data.  The line `current->next = current` is bogus.  It modifies the list *and* creates a cycle.  Not good.

Third, your indents suggest that your `while` loop contained two separate statements, but there is no block scope (*i.e.* `{` ... `}`) around them.  So, only the first statement will be part of the loop.

Finally, a point on style.  Please don't put whitespace around `->`.  While the compiler doesn't care, it makes your code very difficult for humans to read.

Correctly traversing your list is as simple as this:

```
for(struct Node* current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next)
{
    printf("%s\n", current->data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Paddy, but when I added that code at the end of my main function, I ended up with foxfoxfoxfoxfoxfox

Comment: This was meant to be a replacement for the contents of your `traverse_and_printList` function.  If you're still calling that function, then please pay attention to my comment about how your existing code creates a cycle in your list.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just not following you. When I replaced my code with what you suggested, I ended up with 'incompatible pointer to integer conversions.' https://repl.it/@MichaelB4/DeafeningTreasuredMathematics

Comment: You defined your function incorrectly.  By not specifying a type for the `head` parameter, C will assume `int` by default.  Change the definition to `void traverse_and_printList(struct Node* head) { ... }`.  You have other problems that are outside of the scope of your question.  I won't engage in a live debugging session in the comments.  At the very least, you will need to learn how to copy strings, as right now you are storing a pointer to your line buffer.  That means all items in the list will appear to be the same.  There are thousands of questions here about that, or open a book on C.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your 'traverse and print' function has problems.  You have:

```
void traverse_and_printList(head){
    struct Node* current = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    current = head;
    while (head -> next != NULL)
        printf("%s", current -> data);
        current -> next = current;

}
```

- A modern GCC would warn you about misleading indentation — the `current->next = current;` line is not controlled by the `while` loop (C is *not* Python!).
- Testing `head->current` in the loop is wrong; it should be `current->head` that you test.
- As a point of style, the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly and should not have spaces on either side of them.
- A printing function shouldn't do any allocation of nodes.

Because you omitted type information from the function definition line, `head` is interpreted as being an `int` (using the rules of pre-standard C, which C90 had to allow in order to stand a chance of be accepted) — and you must be compiling with a compiler that is not configured to complain about pre-C99 code.  This is the 21st Century; you should not be use 30-year old notations.  Work out how to specify at least C99 and how to get warnings.  With GCC, that would be along the lines of `-std=c99 -Wall -Werror -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes`; I use `-Wextra` too, and often more options still.

```
void traverse_and_printList(struct Node *head)
{
    struct Node *current = head;
    while (current->next != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s", current->data);
        current->next = current;
    }
}
```

Especially while debugging, I'd probably use a format more like the following, surrounding the data with markers (I chose `[[` and `]]`, but the choice is yours), because it can reveal problems (such as unwanted `'\r'` at the ends of lines):

```
printf("[[%s]]\n", current->data);
```

I might also print the pointers, too:

```
printf("C %p N %p [[%s]]\n", (void *)current, (void *)current->next, current->data);
```

You might prefer more verbose notations (`Current` instead of `C`; `Next` instead of `N`), but compactness also has its merits.

<sup>*Warning: the revised code has not been near a compiler.*</sup>

Comment: Thanks. I can see I have another error when I'm appending, as the last value passed will be head, which will have a null pointer when passed to the traverse_and_printList function. I'm still not able to manipulate the nodes, pointers well enough, so hopefully, I can get a quick bit of tutoring on codementor to understand what I'm missing.